# Scikit's prediction for linear model

Tags: machine-learning, python, lasso, scikit-learn

Looking at this [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#lasso) for the Lasso method:

```
>>> from sklearn import linear_model
>>> clf = linear_model.Lasso(alpha = 0.1)
>>> clf.fit([[0, 0], [1, 1]], [0, 1])
Lasso(alpha=0.1, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=1000,
   normalize=False, positive=False, precompute=False, random_state=None,
   selection='cyclic', tol=0.0001, warm_start=False)
>>> clf.predict([[1, 1]])
array([ 0.8])
```

Per documentation the `predict` is used to `Predict using the linear model`. If I understand correctly `clf.fit` data is constructed as such:

```
+---+----+----+
| y | x1 | x2 |
+===+====+====+
| 0 | 0  | 0  |
+---+----+----+
| 1 | 1  | 1  |
+---+----+----+
```

So why does the `predict` for `[1,1]` gives a `0.8`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Predict using the linear model" appears to refer to the Lasso's regularized linear model, rather than a standard linear model. These are equivalent to a standard linear model when the regularization parameter is $0$, as mentioned in the docs regarding the `alpha` parameter:

> `alpha = 0` is equivalent to an ordinary least square, solved by the `LinearRegression` object.

The prediction of $0.8$ rather than $1$ is a consequence of the regularization. To see how this parameter affects predictions, you might try variations on this:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
for i in range(10):
    clf = linear_model.Lasso(alpha = 0.1 * i)
    clf.fit([[0, 0], [1, 1]], [0, 1])
    print clf.predict([[1, 1]])
```

Which gives this output:

```
[ 1.]
[ 0.8]
[ 0.6]
[ 0.5]
[ 0.5]
[ 0.5]
[ 0.5]
[ 0.5]
[ 0.5]
[ 0.5]
```

This parameter is often tuned to minimize expected test error, though its utility in doing so isn't clear from this example.

Comment: Very well explained, thank you. So would this be correct, vary `alpha` to minimize the error between my training and test data?

Comment: @Leb No! That's "cheating", by looking at your test data to predict on it. Vary `alpha` to minimize the error on a held-out validation set, possibly by using [`sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html).

Comment: @Dougal sorry about the misuse of terminology, by test data I meant validation set. I will look into the `GridSearch`, thank you.